# How can I reinstall binary file /usr/bin/ld?

Tags: installation, binary

I have inadvertently overwritten file `/usr/bin/ld`. How can I reinstall this file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`dlocate` is quite useful in this case to know for which package it came from:

```
$ dlocate /usr/bin/ld
binutils: /usr/bin/ld.gold
binutils: /usr/bin/ld.bfd
binutils: /usr/bin/ld
libc-bin: /usr/bin/ldd
```

As it can be seen above, `/usr/bin/ld` is available through `binutils` package. Hence, you should be able to get it back by reinstalling that package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils
```

Comment: ...or one can use `dpkg -S /usr/bin/ld` instead of `dlocate`.

Comment: I am getting the following error 
ld --version
Segmentation fault (core dumped)